# Error displaying image linked list

Tags: formula-field, image-formula

I created a formula field that according to check some fields returns the image to the status of the object. In the registration screen, the image is displayed correctly, however when viewing the record in the related list appears another image.

Has anyone had this problem?

Comment: Posting the formula you are using might generate an answer.

Comment: Formula: `code IF(  AND(  LEN(TEXT(Data_de_Pagamento__c)) = 0 , Data_de_Vencimento__c < NOW() ), IMAGE("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=015J0000000VrPW", "Red" , 16,16),
IF( Data_de_Pagamento__c  >  Data_de_Vencimento__c ,IMAGE("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=015J0000000VrNp", "Yellow", 16,16) ,
   IF(AND(  LEN(TEXT(Data_de_Pagamento__c)) > 0 , Data_de_Vencimento__c >= Data_de_Pagamento__c ) , IMAGE("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=015J0000000VrPv", "Green" , 16,16), 
    IMAGE("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=015J0000000Vrb3", "Blue", 16,16) ) ) ) `

Comment: When you say "appears another image", can you confirm that it is still one of the images referenced in the formula e.g. red instead of blue? (I can't think of a cause; perhaps someone else can.)

Comment: Yes, the picture that emerges is referenced in the formula.
example:

In related list record appears with the blue image, however when I go on the page of the record the red image (right image) is shown.

I tried to clear the cache of browser, but still the problem persists.

Comment: The problem has been resolved after updating the browser.